# Ruby, Delayed jobs, Delayed:Backend:Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using delayed jobs like Something.delay.some_function()
I am running [Foreman][1] Procfile to start both rails server and a worker

```
web: bundle exec rails s
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

And all the time I see this in my terminal, though I always run rake jobs:clear if something bad happened during the job. And now I have no delayd jobs

```
irb(main):010:0> Delayed::Job.all
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" 
=> []
```

but I still see those strange things in my terminal. What is this and how can I get rid of it?

```
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:52.491892' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:52.492124') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:5010') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:52.706307' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:52.706499') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:4654') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:52.712781' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:52.713010') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:4313') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (4.8ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:52.710021' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:52.710261') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:4622') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:54.530083' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:54.530318') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:5307') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:57.497068' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:57.497275') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:5010') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:57.723823' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:57.724071') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:4313') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:57.722732' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:57.722934') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:4654') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (10.0ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:57.718190' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:57.718443') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:4622') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
11:47:01 rails_s.1     |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-06-14 09:46:59.534770' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-06-14 05:46:59.535003') OR locked_by = 'host:kik-VirtualBox pid:5307') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delayed Job checks if there are new tasks for it every once in a while. As long as `rake jobs:work` is running you'll be seeing those logs. In short - everything is ok!